# Can a flyway config file include other config files?

Tags: flyway

I'm using the flyway command line tool. I'd like to setup different configuration settings for different environments (development/testing/production), but there will be some common settings. Ideally there can be a `common.properties` config, along with individual environment-specific configs (e.g. `production.properties`)

Does flyway support including properties from multiple config files in some way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can by exploiting the loading order of Flyway config files (http://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/#configFile)

Place the common settings in either

- *Flyway Install Dir*/conf/flyway.conf
- *User Home Dir*/flyway.conf
- *Current Dir*/flyway.conf

You can then put the environment-specific properties in the file you specify with

`-configFile=/path/to/envspecific.conf`